# need awk help to filter/resort in bash

Tags: bash, awk, filter

need some awk help to filter a file and sort into correct format

example file

```
uid=userA
gid=1000
homedirectory=/home/userA

uid=userB
homedirectory=/home/userA
gid=1000
```

you see the series gid/homedirectory is sometimes twisted.

wanted output format is

uid;gid;homedirectory

```
userA;1000;/home/userA
userB;1000;/home/userB
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: A good place to start would be to look at existing, already-answered questions like [Using awk to merge multiple lines into single-line records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516567/using-awk-to-merge-multiple-lines-into-single-line-records-while-removing-some-o). Even if you have trouble applying those answers to the different (simpler) data format you have here, showing the attempt will result in a narrower, more specific question.

Comment: You'll want to read each line, split on `=` and store the pair as key:value in an associative array. When you hit an empty line or eof, print the 3 keys from the array. Make an attempt and we can help you out with any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> mawk -F= '
> function __() { 
>     printf("%s;%s;%s%*s", _["u"], _["g"], _["h"], split(___,_), RS) 
> } { if (NF) {
>             _[sprintf("%c",$___)] = $NF 
>     } else __() 
> } END {    __() } '
> ```

```
userA;1000;/home/userA
userB;1000;/home/userB
```

Comment: it works. my plan was to work on monday on that.
Thank very much to RARE Kpop Manifesto for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
awk  -F"=" 'BEGIN {print "Username;Group-ID;Home-Directory"} /^uid:/{uid=$2}/^homeDirectory: /{home=$2}/^gidNumber:/{gid=$2}/^[dn]/{printf "%s;%s;%s;\n",uid,gid,home}'
```

after little help i have a shorter example for the correct result.

think we can close here.